# Trouble getting PHP file_exists to work

Tags: php, wordpress, file-exists

I'm trying to get a thumbnail to link to a PDF of the same name if the PDF exists, but to not link to anything if the PDF doesn't exist. Here's the code I have:

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
$full_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full') ;
$pdf = substr_replace($full_image_url , 'pdf', strrpos($full_image_url[0] , '.') +1);

$filename = $pdf[0];
if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo '<a href="' . $pdf[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" . target="_blank" >';
the_post_thumbnail('Full Size');
echo '</a>';
  }
else {
echo "The file $filename exists";
  }
 }
?>
```

Currently, the else statement is just to prove whether or not it's finding the file. Which it seems to, as it displays `The file http://localhost/AWAD/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/+D.pdf exists`. And if I get rid of the conditional, the post thumbnail displays with a link to the PDF. I just can't get the conditional to work.

Can anyone spot why it's not working?

Comment: What is the contents of `$pdf[0]`? And what is the location of the PDF in relation to the location of your PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `file_exists` wants a full file path, not a URL. So, you'll probably want to use the WordPress `wp_uploads_dir` function to get the base path to your uploads directory and then append the rest of the path to the end of that and then pass that string to `file_exists`. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so I tried `$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
   $filename = ($uploads['path'] . '/' . basename($pdf[0]));` The else statement now outputs the file path "The file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AWAD/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/+D.pdf exists". The problem is, it's in the 03 folder. How do I get the folder of the original thumbnail?

Comment: Alright, so this worked (though it seems a bit more complicated than it should be, so if anyone has a better way, I'd love to hear it): `$filename = ($uploads['basedir'] . '/' . basename(dirname(dirname($pdf[0]))) . '/' . basename(dirname($pdf[0])) . '/' . basename($pdf[0]));`

Comment: That does look a bit unwieldy. After a bit of research, it looks like you might want the 'get_attached_file' function instead. It will probably be much cleaner, but I haven't used it before myself, so I can't say for sure. See the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file

Answer (score 4):

You should pass a path on your FS to [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php), you are passing an URL now

Comment: Also, depending on the environment once the code is corrected to receive file system paths, be aware that PHP safe mode can negatively affect the results as per the docs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Thanks. I just needed it spelled out a little more.